# How to set interval in background GPS tracking?

Tags: react-native

I am using "react-native-background-geolocation" for user location tracking when the app is in the background.

Then is it possible to set interval in this function when device powered-up again? (on boot)
I want to get the user location constantly in the background once user turn on device.

How to set "setInterval" on this?

That is my code.

```
componentWillMount = async () => {

    // This handler fires whenever bgGeo receives a location update.
    BackgroundGeolocation.onLocation(this.onLocation, this.onError);

    // This handler fires when movement states changes (stationary->moving; moving->stationary)
    BackgroundGeolocation.onMotionChange(this.onMotionChange);

    // This event fires when a change in motion activity is detected
    BackgroundGeolocation.onActivityChange(this.onActivityChange);

    // This event fires when the user toggles location-services authorization
    BackgroundGeolocation.onProviderChange(this.onProviderChange);

    ////
    // 2.  Execute #ready method (required)
    //
    BackgroundGeolocation.ready(
      {
        // Geolocation Config
        desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.DESIRED_ACCURACY_HIGH,
        distanceFilter: 10,
        // Activity Recognition
        stopTimeout: 1,
        // Application config
        debug: true, // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
        logLevel: BackgroundGeolocation.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE,
        stopOnTerminate: false, // <-- Allow the background-service to continue tracking when user closes the app.
        startOnBoot: true, // <-- Auto start tracking when device is powered-up.
        // HTTP / SQLite config
        url: 'http://yourserver.com/locations',
        batchSync: false, // <-- [Default: false] Set true to sync locations to server in a single HTTP request.
        autoSync: true, // <-- [Default: true] Set true to sync each location to server as it arrives.
        headers: {
          // <-- Optional HTTP headers
          'X-FOO': 'bar',
        },
        params: {
          // <-- Optional HTTP params
          auth_token: 'maybe_your_server_authenticates_via_token_YES?',
        },
      },
      (state) => {
        console.log(
          '- BackgroundGeolocation is configured and ready: ',
          state.enabled,
        );

        if (!state.enabled) {
          ////
          // 3. Start tracking!
          //
          BackgroundGeolocation.start(function () {
            console.log('- Start success');
          });
        }
      },
    );
  };
```